# Robust Standard Errors in lm() using stargazer()

Tags: stargazer, robust

I have read a lot about the pain of replicate the easy robust option from STATA to R to use robust standard errors. I replicated following approaches: [StackExchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117052/replicating-statas-robust-option-in-r/117066?newreg=56d3029c56e0476a9061f8fb64380c35) and [Economic Theory Blog](https://economictheoryblog.com/2016/08/07/robust-standard-errors-in-r-function/). They work but the problem I face is, if I want to print my results using the `stargazer` function (this prints the `.tex` code for Latex files).

Here is the illustration to my problem:

```
reg1 <-lm(rev~id + source + listed + country , data=data2_rev)
stargazer(reg1)
```

This prints the R output as .tex code (non-robust SE) If i want to use robust SE, i can do it with the sandwich package as follow:

```
vcov <- vcovHC(reg1, "HC1")
```

if I now use stargazer(vcov) only the output of the vcovHC function is printed and not the regression output itself.

With the package `lmtest()` it is possible to print at least the estimator, but not the observations, R2, adj. R2, Residual, Residual St.Error and the F-Statistics.

```
lmtest::coeftest(reg1, vcov. = sandwich::vcovHC(reg1, type = 'HC1'))
```

This gives the following output:

```
t test of coefficients:

            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept) -2.54923    6.85521 -0.3719 0.710611   
id           0.39634    0.12376  3.2026 0.001722 **
source       1.48164    4.20183  0.3526 0.724960   
country     -4.00398    4.00256 -1.0004 0.319041   
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

How can I add or get an output with the following parameters as well?

```
Residual standard error: 17.43 on 127 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.09676,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.07543 
F-statistic: 4.535 on 3 and 127 DF,  p-value: 0.00469
```

Did anybody face the same problem and can help me out? 
How can I use robust standard errors in the `lm` function and apply the `stargazer` function?

Comment: I'm pretty sure none of those statistics depend on the variance-covariance matrix, just the residuals and the variance of y, sample size, df, etc. So the output would be the same. see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5135/interpretation-of-rs-lm-output

Answer (score 13):

You already calculated robust standard errors, and there's an easy way to include it in the `stargazer`output:

```
library("sandwich")
library("plm")
library("stargazer")

data("Produc", package = "plm")

# Regression    
model <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp,
             data = Produc, 
             index = c("state","year"),
             method="pooling")

# Adjust standard errors
cov1         <- vcovHC(model, type = "HC1")
robust_se    <- sqrt(diag(cov1))

# Stargazer output (with and without RSE)
stargazer(model, model, type = "text",
          se = list(NULL, robust_se))
```

Solution found here: https://www.jakeruss.com/cheatsheets/stargazer/#robust-standard-errors-replicating-statas-robust-option

**Update** I'm not so much into F-Tests. People are discussing those issues, e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93787/f-test-formula-under-robust-standard-error

When you follow http://www3.grips.ac.jp/~yamanota/Lecture_Note_9_Heteroskedasticity

"A heteroskedasticity-robust t statistic can be obtained by dividing an OSL estimator by its robust standard error (for zero null hypotheses).  The usual F-statistic, however, is invalid.  Instead, we need to use the heteroskedasticity-robust Wald statistic."

and use a Wald statistic here?

Comment: Thanks @marco! But this only explains how to manually add the F-statistics. But furst i have to know my f statistics of the overall regression with the robust SE. Does it remain the same as without RSE?

Comment: Hi @HAL_71 in the sense of stackoverflow, please accept my answer, when it solves the initial problem (as it says in the heading, robust standard errors in stargazer). I think you can try the wald test, instead of F statistic. If you need more information about some econometric background, I suggest to open a new thread on cross-validated. Best regards

Comment: Hi, I'm looking  for a way to include robust SEs in stargazer from [link](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survival/versions/3.3-1/topics/clogit) model output. It has robust and cluster option, but I can't get it to print the robust SEs and pvalues in stargazer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly simple solution using coeftest:

```
reg1 <-lm(rev~id + source + listed + country , data=data2_rev)
cl_robust <- coeftest(reg1, vcov = vcovCL, type = "HC1", cluster = ~ 
   country)
se_robust <- cl_robust[, 2]
stargazer(reg1, reg1, cl_robust, se = list(NULL, se_robust, NULL))
```

Note that I only included cl_robust in the output as a verification that the results are identical.