# How to calculate robust standard errors in stargazer for plm (pooling) model in R?

Tags: r, rstudio, regression, stargazer, plm

I have several regression models using `plm` and `pooling`. My data is a pooled cross sectional / time series data, with data on bond issuances. The data consists of observations of around 2000 bond issuances, with around 25 bond-descriptive variables.

I want to calculate the robust standard errors for one or all of the regression models, in order to add it in my stargazer visualization. My regressions are as follows:

```
#Regression    
primaryreg4 <- plm(issueyield ~ issuer + exchange + yearmonth + maturity.cat + size.cat + coupontype, 
                   data = data, 
                   index = c("ID", "issuedate"), 
                   model = "pooling")
```

All the variables are fixed effects (FE), so they are dummy variables. I want to calculate the robust standard errors of this model, and add it to stargazer. The code I have tried in order to calculate the standard errors is:

```
cov.r4 <- vcovHC(primaryreg4, type = "HC3")
robust_se_r4 <- sqrt(diag(cov.r4))

# or (it is the same)

robust_se_r4 <- sqrt(diag(vcovHC(primaryreg4, type = "HC3")))
```

I would then specify the standard errors in stargazer to be `robust_se_r`. However, i get this error message:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 15.8 Gb

Does anyone know how to solve this? I understand that it is a memory problem, but the file really should not be too big - my data is about 2000 observations of 25 variables (not too big!).

Comment: Can you make the data available somewhere? Or provide a self-contained reproducible example?

Answer (score -1):

Your code is running on minimal panel data:

```
library("plm")
data("Produc", package = "plm")

# Regression    
model <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp,
          data = Produc, 
          index = c("state","year"),
          method="pooling")

# Robust Standard Errors
robust_se <- sqrt(diag(vcovHC(model, type = "HC3")))
```

Can you describe your variable more in detail? What categories does maturity and size have? Try `glimpse` from `dplyr` to check the data type and format of each variable.

Comment: I think his question was how to print robust standard errors for a Latex table using stargazer (or texreg). If there is a quick way to do so for multiple regressions in the same table, I would be very happy to know as well.

Comment: Hi Bob, I added RSE in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58923112/robust-standard-errors-in-lm-using-stargazer There is an `se` option in `stargazer`