# how can I use the stargazer package in R to report the lm.cluster()

Tags: r, lm, stargazer

alldata5 is my data and OROA,IROA,UROA,X2Y,PGR,LTA,gcode are different variables in this

```
basico2<-lm(alldata5$OROA~alldata5$X2Y+alldata5$PGR+alldata5$LTA+factor(alldata5$gcode))


basici2<-lm(alldata5$IROA~alldata5$X2Y+alldata5$PGR+alldata5$LTA+factor(alldata5$gcode))


basicu2<-lm(alldata5$UROA~alldata5$X2Y+alldata5$PGR+alldata5$LTA+factor(alldata5$gcode))


stargazer(basico2,basici2,basicu2, dep.var.labels=c("OROA","IROA","UROA"),
          omit="gcode",type="html", out="E:\\1.basic ols output\\1.1two year.ols.htm")
```

[image]

I can use stargazer for lm() function,but how can I use it for lm.cluster() function?Like:

```
library( miceadds)


basico2c<-lm.cluster(data=alldata5,formula=OROA~X2Y+PGR+LTA+factor(gcode),cluster="year")


basici2c<-lm.cluster(data=alldata5,formula=IROA~X2Y+PGR+LTA+factor(gcode),cluster="year")


basicu2c<-lm.cluster(data=alldata5,formula=UROA~X2Y+PGR+LTA+factor(gcode),cluster="year")
```

It will be faild if I use

```
stargazer(basico2C,basici2C,basicu2C, dep.var.labels=c("OROA","IROA","UROA"), omit="gcode",type="html", out="E:\1.basic ols output\1.1two year.ols.htm")
```

Comment: Or if i don't use lm.cluster() function,do you know any function that i can use then have the output like the picture shows? If anyone know the answer,please let me know, thank you very much!

Comment: In https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/vignettes/stargazer.pdf 2.3 you find a list of supported statistical models. Looks like `miceadds` is not included. Perhaps you find some supported package which supports clusters.

Comment: Yes, Marco, I think so. Thank you very much. I may use STATA to export the output, it's more convenient than R while doing the regression

Comment: I meant, you can use another package in R to calculate clustered robust standard errors, which in turn can be used in `stargazer` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58923112/robust-standard-errors-in-lm-using-stargazer/59156668#59156668

Comment: @MarcoDoe  I got it now. Thanks again!